# Symfony2: How can I change the value of a variable of a parent render?

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, parent-child, symfony-2.1

I hope someone can help me with this topic.

I have two controller in a Symfony 2 structure, the second one override the first.

Here the code of the parent controller:

```
<?php

namespace WebSender\MainPageBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $Header_Title = "Titolo 1";
        $content_area = "Contenuto di prova 1!";
        $Header_Welcome = "Benvenuto utente: ";
        $username = "nome utente";
        $Header_Logout = "Logout";

        return $this->render('WebSenderMainPageBundle:Default:index.html.php', array('Header_Title' => $Header_Title, 'content_area' => $content_area, 'Header_Welcome' => $Header_Welcome, 'username' => $username, 'Header_Logout' => $Header_Logout));
    }
}
```

And the second controller:

```
<?php

namespace WebSender\MainPageBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 

use WebSender\MainPageBundle\Controller\DefaultController as BaseController;

class GridController extends BaseController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $Header_Title = "Titolo 2";
        $content_area = "Contenuto di prova 2!";

        $response = parent::indexAction();

        // return $this->render('WebSenderMainPageBundle:Default:index.html.php', array('Header_Title' => $Header_Title, 'content_area' => $content_area, 'Header_Welcome' => $Header_Welcome, 'username' => $username, 'Header_Logout' => $Header_Logout));
        return $response;
   }
}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to change $response values, especially "content_area" and "Header_Title".

Thanks.

Comment: In Symfony you can override a controller with a new one: in other words you "extend" all or part of the controller with another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is: you just can't do it because render method returns Response object with ready-to-serve html. In other words - when you get your resopnse from render method, the twig's job is completed.

It's hard to say what will be the best solution for you, because I guess the example you've posted is not real one, but just simplified one.

For example if your two actions will generate the same page, with only title and footer differences - use twig's inheritance instead of controller inheritance, and put these literals inside templates.

On the other hand - if these things are generated by logic, use appropriate "logic" service to serve them, and then you don't need controller inheritance anymore.

If my answer is not enough for you, please tell more what you are trying achieve and I'll try help you in more detailed way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I will "re-think" the logic: I was strying to "force" the logic creation of the variables. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use template inheritance with twig.

This way you define block with the title you want for the extended controller. As cyprian said, you need to move this logic